# TrueCrypt Corrupted Files

Tags: truecrypt

Several months ago, I needed to reorganize my data across multiple external hard drives with my laptops primary hard drive as the go-between. My external hard drives are all encrypted with TrueCrypt.

It appears to me that somehow during the transfer of my files between the encrypted external drive an the unencrypted internal drive, the files were transferred "as-is" (in their encrypted state). The files range from very small to very large. It appears that this may have happened during one consecutive transfer session.

Has anyone ever experienced this problem, and if so were you able to fix it? Is there a way to recreate the encrypted partition, transfer the files, and then decrypt them to their usable state? Or can the files somehow be decrypted through other means?

**UPDATE:**
I am running Windows 7 (x64) HP now, but may have been runninG ENT. then. Toshiba Laptop 650GB HDD / 4GB Mem. Latest version of TC

Comment: What Platform/OS and Truecrypt version? Please edit your question add more information about your system.

Comment: If you were able to see the files, and view their contents, then they are not transfed as an encrypted file.  If the files are corrupted then there is not much you can do about it now.

Comment: I can view the file name, but the content of the file itself is jiberish